# PowerShell上でシンボリックリンクやジャンクションを作るには？

Tags: powershell

コマンドプロンプトやバッチファイルでは `mklink` コマンドを使ってシンボリックリンクやジャンクションを作ることができますが、PowerShell 上ではこのコマンドが使えないようです。

```
PS C:\Users\test> mklink
mklink : 用語 'mklink' は、コマンドレット、関数、スクリプト ファイル、または
操作可能なプログラムの名前として認識されません。名前が正しく記述されていること
を確認し、パスが含まれている場合はそのパスが正しいことを確認してから、再試行してください。
```

PowerShell なら専用のコマンドレットとか、あるいは.NET経由で作れてもいいような気がするのですが、 `cmd /c mklink` などとして `cmd.exe` 経由で実行するしかないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mklinkはcmd.exeの内部コマンドであり、独立した実行ファイルではありません。

[PowerShell で シンボリックリンクを 使えるようにしよう](http://tech.guitarrapc.com/entry/2014/08/19/022232)が参考になります。またこの中で触れられているようにシンボリックリンクに関しては`New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink`で作れるようです。

Comment: PowerShell v5 から `New-Item` で作れるの、いいですね。調べてみると `HardLink` や `Junction` も指定できるようで。 http://stackoverflow.com/a/31863275/2818869

Comment: @unarist さん、[New-Itemのドキュメント](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849795.aspx)には`SymbolicLink`しか書かれていませんでしたが、ドキュメント不足なだけでしたか…。